# How can i use/insert HashTable Key and values into a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to use HashTable keys & value in a JTable.
How can i do this ?

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? What does the Hashtable contain? What do you want the JTable to contain?

Comment: My Hashtable is of String Type and i want that table contains two columns and left side key & right side corrosponding values will display

Answer (score 4):

first: make yourself familiar with the use of tables

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

and datamodels

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html

if you know, how to add data in a JTable, you can iterate over your HastTable by a foreach-loop

```
for(Map.Entry<K,V> entry : hashTable.entrySet()) {
```

for further information, see

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

and

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html

Comment: I saw you suggested sites but I have to comlplete this task within a specific time...so can u sugges me more..

Comment: Your best bet is to read/study the sites and learn from them. This way you'll complete your task *and* understand what you're doing. 1+ to Hachi for good advice. If you're still crunched for time, check out [this site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_management) which also has good tips and links.

Comment: Ok thanks sir for ur precious advicew..ok last tell me that how can i store the hashtable key and values in different array/Vector.

Comment: if you want somebody else to do _your_ work instead of learning how-to do it yourself, pay her/him ;-)